# Python and default dict, how to pprint

Tags: python

I am using default dict.  I need to `pprint`.

However, when I `pprint` ...this is how it looks.

```
defaultdict(<functools.partial object at 0x1f68418>, {u'300:250': defaultdict(<functools.partial object at 0x1f683c0>, {0: defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {u'agid1430864021': {u'status': u'0', u'exclude_regi..........
```

How to I get `pprint` to work with default dict?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I've used `pprint(dict(defaultdict))` before as a work-around.

Comment: I've found this solution does not give the desired effect if the object is a nested hierarchy of deafultdict objects.

Comment: For nested defaultdicts: `pprint({k: dict(v) for k, v in dict(group_ids).items()})`

Answer (score 25):

The best solution I've found is a bit of a hack, but an elegant one (if a hack can ever be):

```
class PrettyDefaultDict(collections.defaultdict):
    __repr__ = dict.__repr__
```

And then use the `PrettyDefaultDict` class instead of `collections.defaultdict`. It works because of the way the pprint module works (at least on 2.7):

```
r = getattr(typ, "__repr__", None)
if issubclass(typ, dict) and r is dict.__repr__:
    # follows pprint dict formatting
```

This way we "trick" pprint into thinking that our dictionary class is just like a normal `dict`.

Comment: @rossoft did you actually test that bit of advice (`defaultdict.__repr__ = dict.__repr__`) before telling us we can do that?

Comment: @Aaron Hall: it worked for me on Python 2.7. If you had a problem, tell us what it was.

Comment: @mhsmith My question is addressed to rossoft, who must have deleted his message. But RedGlow's code could use a demo.

Comment: Ah yes, I obviously wouldn't recommend monkey-patching defaultdict itself.

Answer (score 18):

If you don't have to use `pprint`, you can use `json` to pretty-print the `defaultdict`:

```
print(json.dumps(my_default_dict, indent=4))
```

This also works for nested defaultdicts.

Comment: if your keys are not strings this will mess up your print

Answer (score 5):

I really like this solution for dealing with nested defaultdicts. It's a bit of a hack, but does the job neatly when pdbing:

```
import json
data_as_dict = json.loads(json.dumps(data_as_defaultdict))
print(data_as_dict)
```

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32303615/4526633

Answer (score 4):

In the same vein as Jon Clements' answer, if this is a common operation for you, you might consider subclassing defaultdict to override its repr method, as shown below.

**Input:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

class prettyDict(defaultdict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        defaultdict.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(dict(self))

foo = prettyDict(list)

foo['bar'].append([1,2,3])
foo['foobar'].append([4,5,6,7,8])

print(foo)
```

**Output:**

```
{'foobar': [[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]], 'bar': [[1, 2, 3]]}
```