# How to create a special dictionary with multiple values under one key?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
school = [['dia', 87], ['ria', 100], ['gud', 59], ['ria', 85], ['gud', 76], ['don', 99]]
```

This array contains the students and their marks (yes, there are some duplicate students who are having diff values).

I want to convert it into this dictionary to find the avg score:

```
school_dict = { dia:[87], ria:[100,85], gud:[59,76], don:[99] }
```

Let me know if anyone can solve this for me.

Comment: What have you tried, and how does it fail? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

```
res = {}
for x in school:
    res.setdefault(x[0],[]).append(x[1])
print(res)
```

Output

```
{'dia': [87], 'ria': [100, 85], 'gud': [59, 76], 'don': [99]}
```

Answer (score 1):

From a performance point of view, defaultdict is faster than dict.setdefault(), so you may use that too:

```
from collections import defaultdict
school = [['dia', 87], ['ria', 100], ['gud', 59], ['ria', 85], ['gud', 76], ['don', 99]]
d = defaultdict(list)
for s in school:
    d[s[0]].append(s[1])
print(dict(d))
```

Output:

> {'dia': [87], 'ria': [100, 85], 'gud': [59, 76], 'don': [99]}

Follow this: [setdefault vs defaultdict performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38625608/setdefault-vs-defaultdict-performance) for performance-related discussion.

Comment: thank you so much SagarGuptaFTW. really appreciate it

Comment: @ChirantanSaha No problem. You may accept the answer if it helped.