# Join N dictionaries in one

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to join dictionaries in this way:

```
d1 = {1: [1, 2, 3], 2: [5, 4, 35]}
d2 = {1: [4, 5, 6], 2: [32, 54, 102]}
d3 = {3: [943, 23, 111, 3], 1: [7, 8, 9]}

dictionary_result = {1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 2: [5, 4, 35, 32, 54, 102], 3: [943, 23, 111,3]}
```

I tried this, but only works for 2 dictionaries

```
from collections import defaultdict
a, b = {1: [2, 3], 2: [3]}, {1: [4], 3: [1]}
de = defaultdict(list, a)
for i, j in b.items():
    de[i].extend(j)
```

So, how can I join N dictionaries like this efficiently?

Comment: Look why defaultdict is better than setdefault https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38625608/setdefault-vs-defaultdict-performance and maybe change the accepted answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use dictionary method [**`setdefault`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault).
This is how `setdefault` works: If the key is in the dictionary it returns its value otherwise insert a key with a value of default(which is a `list` in this case) and return default.

```
dictionary_result = {}
for d in d1, d2, d3:
    for key, value in d.items():
        dictionary_result.setdefault(key, []).extend(value)
```

**Output:**

```
{1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 2: [5, 4, 35, 32, 54, 102], 3: [943, 23, 111, 3]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add an outer loop, that runs over the different `dicts` to use as update:

```
result = defaultdict(list)
for d in d1, d2, d3:
    for i, j in d.items():
        result[i].extend(j)
```

Comment: No reason to treat `d1` differently; just start with an empty `defaultdict(list)`. The way this currently works, you're mutating the lists in `d1`, which is probably undesirable.

Comment: @kaya3 It avoid looping over it, so better performance

Comment: How exactly do you think `defaultdict(list, d1)` avoids looping over `d1`?

Comment: @kaya3 don't really know how is the implem, I'd guess it doesn't iterate over the dict, but use it directly or smth