# How can I add multiple keys to a python Dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, web-scraping, data-analysis

I have a web scraper that grabs info and saves it to a database. I use the following code to save data.

```
try: 
    base['vevo']['url']
except:
    base['vevo']['url'] = "NotGiven"
try: 
    base['vevo']['viewsLastWeek']['data']['time']
except:
    base['vevo']['viewsLastWeek']['data']['time'] = '2199-01-01'
```

Now normally this works, however ocassionally the data stream doesn't return any info at all for `base['vevo']`.  This breaks the above dict add and says that `KeyError 'vevo'`.

I've been trolling through other stackoverflow questions, but I haven't been able to find anything that references adding multiple keys at once like I'm trying to do. I've tried to use base.append('key'), tried base.get() but couldn't find a reference on how to use it for multiple keys deep.  Any ideas on how to get around it?

Comment: Have you tried `get()` with a default value, eg :  `base.get('vevo', {})`

Comment: What would I put for the {}? And how would this work for ['vevo']['viewsLastWeek']['data']['time']?  I don't fully understand how to use the base.get(), but I feel like it may be the solution

Comment: You can also put another try except like 
try: base['vevo'] except base['vevo']= "not Found vevo"

Comment: base.get( key, defaultvalue) means that if the key does not exist then the key  has this defaultvalue

Comment: Would I have to just keep assigning "NotFound" to every key up the tree then? something like `base['vevo']['viewsLastWeek'] = "NotFound"` , then `base['vevo']['viewsLastWeek']['data'] = "NotFound"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution, but it involved a change in logic instead of what I had originally tried to do.

Since I was only using the dictionary value to save to my database, I could use a place holder variable as an in-between for the functions.  See below for the working code..

```
try: 
    v_url = base['vevo']['url']
except:
    v_url = "NotGiven"
```

Adding values to the existing dictionary proved to be too complicated, and this solution involves no extra packages.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

```
import collections
def new_level():
    return collections.defaultdict(new_level)
base=new_level()
```

This would allow you to add an arbitrary number of levels to your nested dicts:

```
 >>> base["foo"]["bar"]["foobar"]=42
 {'foo': {'bar': {'foobar': 42}}}
```

Comment: This seems to have gotten past the first problem, however now when I `print base['vevo']['url']` it gives me `defaultdict(<function new_level at 0xb4825bc4>, {}`.  It also seemed to do that for all the exisiting values in the dictionary as well. Do I have to do something else to view the actual value afterwords?

Comment: You could use `json` to style the string representation: `print json.dumps(base)`. Or there are other solutions here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925052/python-and-default-dict-how-to-pprint

Comment: Oh no, wait. What happens is that when you call `base['vevo']['url']` and it doesn't exist, it will call `new_level` and create a dictionary. If you want to check if a key exists use `"url" in base['vevo']` to avoid creating a new nested dictionary.